# Identity Insert error being thrown whether i specify identity or not

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm getting

> "An explicit value for the identity column in table can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON."

Whether I specify the identity or not, the exact same error. I do not want to specify the identity and I'm not inserting it anywhere I can see atleast. Here is my (edit, jcolebrand) "relevant" C# code:

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
this.getControls(this.Controls);

con.Open();

/* jcolebrand moved the sql query text further down, it's long */

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

cmd = getVals(cmd);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("event_link", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("event_approved", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("event_in_csi", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("event_in_website", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date_added", DateTime.Now.ToString());
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("event_start_time1", DBNull.Value);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("event_end_time1", DBNull.Value);

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("program", DBNull.Value);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("event_owner", DBNull.Value);


cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

con.Close(); 

String query = @"INSERT INTO [rec_serv].[dbo].[recserv_event1] (
                      event_name
                    , event_category
                    , event_location
                    , event_instructor
                    , event_start_date
                    , event_end_date
                    , event_start_time
                    , event_end_time
                    , event_deadline
                    , member_fee
                    , non_member_fee
                    , email
                    , registration
                    , minimum_size
                    , maximum_size
                    , waiting_list
                    , event_detail
                    , monday
                    , tuesday
                    , wednesday
                    , thursday
                    , friday
                    , saturday
                    , sunday
                    , number_handout
                    , color_handout
                    , size_handout
                    , number_poster
                    , color_poster
                    , size_poster
                    , listserv
                    , news_release
                    , web_banner
                    , visix_ad
                    , desired_displayed_date
                    , other1
                    , other2
                    , comment
                    , event_link
                    , event_approved
                    , event_in_csi
                    , event_in_website
                    , date_added
                    , extracomment
                    , receiptinfo
                    , program
                    , event_owner
                    , event_start_time1
                    , event_end_time1
                ) VALUES (
                    @event_name, 
                    @event_category, 
                    @event_location, 
                    @event_instructor, 
                    @event_start_date, 
                    @event_end_date, 
                    @event_start_time, 
                    @event_end_time, 
                    @event_deadline, 
                    @member_fee, 
                    @non_member_fee, 
                    @email, 
                    @registration, 
                    @minimum_size, 
                    @maximum_size,
                    @waiting_list, 
                    @event_detail, 
                    @monday, 
                    @tuesday, 
                    @wednesday, 
                    @thursday, 
                    @friday, 
                    @saturday,
                    @sunday, 
                    @number_handout, 
                    @color_handout, 
                    @size_handout, 
                    @number_poster, 
                    @color_poster, 
                    @size_poster, 
                    @listserv, 
                    @news_release, 
                    @web_banner, 
                    @visix_ad, 
                    @desired_displayed_date, 
                    @other1, 
                    @other2, 
                    @comment, 
                    @event_link, 
                    @event_approved, 
                    @event_in_csi,
                    @event_in_website,
                    @date_added,
                    @extracomment,
                    @receiptinfo,
                    @program,
                    @event_owner,
                    @event_start_time1,
                    @event_end_time1
);"
```

Comment: Do you have any triggers ON INSERT for the table?

Comment: No I do not have any triggers.

Comment: What is the column name in that table with identity insert on? I think its one of the column that you are trying to insert and you are not aware of it.

Comment: Well your INSERT staement has no column list, just the values. This may cause problems, if your identity column is not the first column in your table definition.

Comment: the column name is id, and id is the first column in the table

Comment: @Mithrandir found the problem !

Comment: @Mithrandir, you should post an answer with your finding so the OP can accept it (it's fair given that you found it first)

Comment: Something odd here, the OP states that the Identity column is called ID and in the refactored code there is no ID. However I don't understand the incomplete `AddWithValue` and what's the purpose of that `getVals(cmd)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use explicit columns when possible in SQL. So, for this query, it would change the form of the query to:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2...);
```

This is also important because it more clearly defines the contract between the application and the SQL database, allowing for future changes.

Answer (score 2):

As Mithrandir mentioned, you're not specifying a column list.  Since your identity column is your first column, why are you passing in `@event_name`?  This is why you are getting the error -- you are trying to set the value of the identity column to `@event_name`, which is incorrect on several levels.  The fix is to make sure you pass in the column list before `VALUES`.

Comment: the id auto increments is the identity, otherwise everything else is in order

Comment: I'm not sure you understand.  The point is that the first *value* specified in your (...) list of values is the identity column.  It's *impossible* to *not* perform an identity insert (which you are trying to avoid) when you do not specify a column list.

Comment: Ok, well i did what you asked, and i'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Since your updated code would not compile (missing concatenation operators) I can't help but be dubious that you actually tried it.  (perhaps you simply didn't realize the compile failed?)

Comment: I at least fixed the query so that it should work, the particular string. If OP doesn't change anything. However, that made me re-out-of-order the text so it could be read more succintly.

Answer (score 1):

Which fields are set by the insert is not determined by the values, it's determined by the fields that you specify in the query. As you haven't specified any fields at all, the default is all fields.

Specify the fields, so that you can avoid the identity field:

```
INSERT INTO table (
  event_name, event_category, event_in_website, date_added, extracomment,
  recipientinfo, program, event_owner, event_start_time1, event_end_time1
) VALUES (
  @event_name, @event_category, @event_in_website, @date_added, @extracomment,
  @receiptinfo, @program, @event_owner, @event_start_time1, @event_end_time1
)
```

Comment: Please show ALL your code @user967713. Don't leave any of it out. Edit your original question to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing your query, execute
"SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[recserv_event1] ON"

eg

```
con.Open(); 
var query =  "SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[recserv_event1] ON";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con); 
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

query = "Your insert statment.";
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 

con.Close();
```

Comment: Your code leaves the IDENTITY_INSERT ON, its a don't do that on the books

Comment: Once the connection is closed. You will need to set IDENTITY_INSERT ON again.